# Showing that an operator is the projection

Tags: linear-algebra

So I'm having trouble with this exercise, so I hope someone can help me.

Let $V$ be a inner product space, and $L:V\rightarrow V$ a linear operator, which satisfies $L^2=L$. Suppose there exists $w\in V,w\neq 0$, such that $L(V)=\text{span}(w)$ and if $v$ is orthogonal on $w$, then $L(v)=0$.

Now I have to prove that $L$ is the orthogonal projection on $w$ for all $v\in V$.

It is clear that $L(v)=\alpha w$ for all $v\in V$. I'm not sure how I can prove that $\alpha =\frac{\left<v,w \right>}{\left< w,w\right>}$ though. Can anyone help me with that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $v \in V$, then $v - L(v) \in \ker(L)$. As $w^\perp$ and $\ker(L)$ are hyperplanes, and $w^\bot$ is contained in $\ker(L)$, we must have $\ker(L) = w^\bot$. So, $v - L(v) \,\bot\, w$. That is, with $L(v) = \alpha w$,
$$ \def\<#1>{\left\langle #1 \right\rangle}\<v - \alpha w, w> = 0 \iff \alpha = \frac{\<v,w>}{\<w,w>} $$

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. I only have one question. I'm not sure I understand how you obtain that
$\text{ker}(L)\subset w^\perp $

Comment: Sry. Had an error in writing, I intended to write $w^\bot \subseteq \ker(L)$, as you state ... now use, that both are hyperolanes ...

Comment: Last question. This might be pretty stupid. How do you know that $\text{Ker}(L)$ is a hyperplane? (1-dimensional subspace, right?).

Comment: @user112110 It should be $1$-co-dimensional subspace. And you can use the rank-nullity theorem.

Comment: 1-codimensional subspace. As $L \ne 0$ (from $w \ne 0$), we have $L(w) = w$, We will show that $V = \ker(L) + span(w)$. Let $v \in V$, then $v = v - L(v) + L(v)$, with $(v - L(v)) \in \ker(L)$, $L(v) \in span(w)$. Hence $\ker(L)$ is 1-codimensional

Comment: Cool! Thanks a lot, that was a great help :)